# Django template convertion error when a number with thousand separator

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have some decimal values with thousand separators passed into a Django template as a list. It should be interpreted as a float value to do some JavaScript calculations. However, due to the thousand separator it causing problems in the list iterations. See the code below as interpreted in the template. I have highlighted the values that have problems. Also note that I want a thousand separators for other places, so it can not be turned off globally. I used the `floatformat` filter but no luck.

data: `[0.00, 0.00, **35,200**.23, **2,910**.36, **1,677**.00, 0.00,],`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [unlocalize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/formatting/#unlocalize).

```
{% load l10n %}

{{ value|unlocalize }}
```